# Php copy text from url

Tags: php

Ι don't know how to well write this. I am trying to make a `.php` file with the name `copy_from_url_=_.php`. Then, I'd like as soon as user enters an url before dot, the contents of the specific url to be displayed on the above `.php` site.

Example: I go to url `copy_from_url_=_.php`. Nothing is displayed because no url is given. Then I retype `copy_from_url_=_www.example.com.php` and the contents of `www.example.com` are displayed on my php url.

I know the second part that can be done with the **[file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)** function but I miss the first part. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validate the `$_GET` value. This will tell you if anything is there (and is a valid format)

```
if( filter_var($_GET['copy_from_url'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) ) {
    //URL given!
    //Either use cURL or file_get_contents
} else {
   //No url given
}
```

The the sake of readability/niceness/OCD, I would remove the ending `.php`. It'll help the end-user experience quickly identify where they are coping from. However, if you don't want to, do the following;

```
$strUrl = rtrim($_GET['copy_from_url'], '.php');
if( filter_var($strUrl, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) ) {
```

https://eval.in/200283